# Autohotkey - how can I detect if the clipboard contains a file?

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to use Autohotkey to determine if the clipboard contains a file.

I can view text contents of the clipboard with`msgbox %clipboard%`, and if I have a file copied in the clipboard then `%clipboard%` returns the file-path, but it's not possible only from this to tell the difference between a text string that looks like a file path or if it's an actual file.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Persistent

OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged")
return

ClipChanged(type) {
    If  (type == 1)  ; the clipboard contains text or files copied
    {
        If (DllCall("IsClipboardFormatAvailable", "uint", 15)) ; the clipboard contains files
            ToolTip, file(s) copied:`n`n%clipboard%
        else  ; the clipboard contains text 
            ToolTip, text copied:`n`n%clipboard%
    }
    else
    If  (type == 2)  ; the clipboard contains images
        ToolTip, image(s) copied
    Sleep, 1000
    ToolTip
}
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/OnClipboardChange.htm#function

**EDIT:**

To check at any time whether the clipboard contains files,
you can define a hotkey:

```
F1::
    If (DllCall("IsClipboardFormatAvailable", "uint", 15)) ; the clipboard contains files
         MsgBox, 64,, The clipboard contains the file(s):`n`n%clipboard%
    else
         MsgBox, 64,, The clipboard doesn't contain any files
return
```

Comment: See also EDIT in this answer.